# something wrong with irrational numbers

Tags: number-systems

$$(5-\sqrt2)(5+\sqrt2)=5^2-\left(\sqrt2\right)^2=25-2=23$$

But as some general rule of mathematics, if a rational number is added or subtracted from or to an irrational number the result is an irrational number but in above example there's something wrong

As per rules $(5-\sqrt2)$ and $(5+\sqrt2)$, both would be irrational and if we multiply both these irrational terms we get an irrational number which do not match to our result $23$.

How's that possible??

Comment: How does multiplying the two numbers give you a irrational number?

Comment: So according to your reasoning $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}=2$ must be irrational!!!

Comment: The numbers $\pi$ and $1/\pi$ are both irrational, but their product is $1$.

Comment: Would love to see the source of this so-called rule

Comment: The only rule in this context, really, is that if $a+b = c$ or $ab = c$ (with $c\neq 0$), then we cannot have that _exactly one_ of $a, b, c$ are irrational. We can have that none of them are, and we can have that two or three of them are, but not one.

Comment: "*as some general rule of mathematics*": what rule?

Comment: "...if a rational number is added or subtracted from or to an irrational number..." You didn't do this. What you did was to multiply an irrational number by another irrational number.

Answer (score 2):

> if a rational number is added or subtracted from or to an irrational number the result is an irrational number

*Added* yes, but that's not what you're doing.

Note that the rational numbers are closed under addition and multiplication since:
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad+bc}{bc} \in \mathbb{Q} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{a}{b}\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ac}{bd} \in \mathbb{Q}$$

This doesn't hold for irrational numbers.

You are *multiplying two irrational numbers* and the result need not be irrational, since for example: $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2} = 2 \in \mathbb{Q}$. The same goes for addition: $\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)+\sqrt{2} = 1\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

The rules are

- rational + rational $\to$ rational
- rational + irrational $\to$ irrational
- irrational + irrational $\to$ any (think of $a+(-a)=0$)
- rational $\times$ rational $\to$ rational
- rational $\times$ irrational $\to$ irrational
- irrational $\times$ irrational $\to$ any (think of $a\times a^{-1}=1$)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if a rational number is added or subtracted from or to an irrational number the result is an irrational number.

But **if you multiply 2 irrational numbers the result isn't always irrational**!

For example: $\sqrt{3}*\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{9}=3 $ and $3\in \Bbb{R}$.